# What are these black tiny dots on the roof of the car?

Tags: toyota, paint

The car is a white Toyota Camry 2012.

As you can see there are many tiny black dots on the roof. I can't remove them by scratching by hand or with a high water pressure cleaner.

[image]

What caused these dots? What can I do to remove them?

Comment: We once had a release of "harmful dust" at a steel plant that damaged the paint of nearby cars. Reminded me of that. Just posting this as a comment to remind that chemical release is of low probability but can still be a possibility

Comment: Are the spots elevated, recessed or even with the paint?

Comment: I too have these little black deposits on my car.  I've tried several cleansers with none being efficient.  Bug and tar remover is my next attempt.  They are more easily removed when the temperature was below 20F.  If you find something that works well, PLEASE let us know.

Comment: Windex or window cleaner with ammonia works well for me, and is a lot cheaper than aerosol BugNTar type removers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like tree sap indeed.

The best way to remove it is to use a clay bar after a good pre clean without putting too much pressure on the paint.

Comment: I have these also.  Paper towel, cloth, sponge and fingernails don't remove them.  I doubt a clay bar will.

Comment: I'd encourage you to try anyway, it will take some time but trust me, all the contaminants will eventually be scraped off. :)

Comment: I do have a clay bar kit that I planned to use after getting all the specks off.  I'll try it a little earlier.  Thanks :-)

Comment: Good! Let us know how it went and don't be afraid to spend some time on it, the result is worth the time investment.

Answer (score 3):

The cause can be one of many possibilities:

fly spots

tree sap

or worse paint overspray

The first two should come off - good cleaner / polish and lots of work, but the paint may mean that you need a re-spray at the worst - there may be a professional treatment that could do it. So go and see a good paintshop and see what they say.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like tar spots to me - unusual to have that many on the roof but not impossible.

Try a dedicated tar remover - Autoglym do a good one (called "Intensive Tar Remover" IIRC) that should have a good chance, it also works well for tree sap (which is another likely culprit).

Answer (score 1):

I removed mine effortlessly with a spray bottle of Spic and Span and a washcloth.

Answer (score 1):

They are artillery fungus caused from parking near wood mulch. Read up on it. Very interesting. Very hard to remove. You must do one at a time. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

We had little black spots all over our Motorhome
We tried Allsorts the only thing that got them off was Pink Stuff paste and a sponge this was amazing.
Pink Stuff available from £1 shops

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely some type of fungus. When I used Clorox cleaner it did come off but I don't want to do alot because I don't  want  to  damage the clear coat

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

My guess is tree sap that then takes in road dust which hardens over time. Just today I’ve tried iron spray and tar remover , no joy, used clean slate by chemical guys too. Gonna finish cleaning the rest of the car and set aside a day or two for this. Going forward I’d recommend getting a good wax or sealant or coating on the roof and keep on top of maintenance.

Comment: That answer has already been given.

Answer (score -2):

Her is a good news video explaining the source of the problem: https://www.wdbj7.com/content/news/Black-spots-on-your-car-could-be-from-a-nearby-fungus-in-your-mulch-509250841.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Along the line of what the bot has posted, we are looking for well fleshed out answers. What you've posted may actually be the answer. What you've posted is a "link only" answer. Links become stale or changed. If you bring the information here and attribute it back to the original source (post the link), your answer will be garner a lot more and better attention. Hope this helps and glad you could join us.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/65566)